# Syncro? Tortoise? Fastest, most reliable Subversion client for Windows 7

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

In XP I used Tortoise, but in Windows 7 I'm reluctant to use something so integrated with the explorer shell. Saw Syncro today but wondered if that was the best standalone GUI or if there was something better. Reasonable cost isn't a problem for me.

Comment: "... I'm reluctant ..." - why?

Comment: @Cavetrob:  Synco looks like a nice standalone.  Thanks for pointing it out.  I may have to take a closer look at it.  http://www.syncrosvnclient.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use tortoise with windows 7 - works fine for me

Comment: As a Subversion admin, I'll take the command line any day of the week over using TortoiseSVN on a Windows system.

Answer (score 1):

Try smartsvn (supports Windows and Linux) - https://www.smartsvn.com/

Answer (score 0):

I use tortoise with windows 7 ,and it works perfectly with me